# strace ordering of system calls does not match expected order

Tags: system-calls, strace

I would expect `strace` run with the test code snippet to output the `write` call ahead of the `open` calls as suggested by the dissambly. Does `puts` perform the write asynchronously somehow or does `strace` reorder the output ?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
   close(1);
   printf("Interesting ordering\n");
   int fd = open("temp.txt", O_RDONLY);
   int fd1 = open("temp.txt", O_RDONLY);
}
```

Strace snippet:

```
munmap(0x7fe46ef45000, 115047)          = 0
close(1)                                = 0
newfstatat(1, "", 0x7fffeea1b980, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
getrandom("\x96\xa6\x6b\xd0\x3c\xde\x09\x28", 8, GRND_NONBLOCK) = 8
brk(NULL)                               = 0xb18000
brk(0xb39000)                           = 0xb39000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "temp.txt", O_RDONLY)  = 1
openat(AT_FDCWD, "temp.txt", O_RDONLY)  = 3
write(1, "Interesting ordering\n", 21)  = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

Disassembly of main:

```cpp
0000000000401146 <main>:
  401146:   55                      push   %rbp
  401147:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40114a:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
  40114e:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
  401153:   e8 e8 fe ff ff          call   401040 <close@plt>
  401158:   bf 10 20 40 00          mov    $0x402010,%edi
  40115d:   e8 ce fe ff ff          call   401030 <puts@plt>
  401162:   be 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%esi
  401167:   bf 25 20 40 00          mov    $0x402025,%edi
  40116c:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  401171:   e8 da fe ff ff          call   401050 <open@plt>
  401176:   89 45 fc                mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
  401179:   be 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%esi
  40117e:   bf 25 20 40 00          mov    $0x402025,%edi
  401183:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  401188:   e8 c3 fe ff ff          call   401050 <open@plt>
  40118d:   89 45 f8                mov    %eax,-0x8(%rbp)
  401190:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  401195:   c9                      leave
  401196:   c3                      ret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order shown by `strace` is correct: it is the order of the *system calls*, and not the library calls.

The call to `printf` is usually buffered, and is not really written until you issue a `fflush`.

The main problem with your code is that you are mixing calls from the `stdio` library with low-level calls such as `write()`; when you do that, the results are undefined and may surprise you.